# How to specify a decimal filter in 'select into table where' in ABAP?

Tags: abap, opensql

I need a query like this in ABAP, but this doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM table
INTO i_tab
WHERE amount = 100,15
```

I've tried:
WHERE amount = '100,15' but that doesn't work either.

How to specify the decimal in my where syntax?

Comment: What is the data type of the column `amount`?

Comment: @vwegert it's WRBTR (CURR 13,2)

Comment: @Marsha: In my country we don't use comma as a decimal separator, we use the dot. In my case I would use: SELECT * FROM table INTO i_tab WHERE amount = '100.15'. Can you try with this syntax? Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I outsmarted it by changing the logic into

```
WHERE amount > 100 AND amount < 101
```

Comment: This does not filter 100,15 records only.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
INTO i_tab
WHERE amount = '100.15'
```

Comment: yes, user specific settings (like using , as a decimal separator) is not taken into account by open SQL

Comment: Not only SQL, but in ABAP too.

Comment: the added quotation marks resulted in an error since the data type of the amount is not a char.